# What is the equation of the line defined by $P(-1,1)$ and $Q(0,2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am learning precalculus and came across the following exercise which I could not solve correctly and could not understand the correct answer.

> An equation of the line passing through the points $P(−1,1)$ and $Q(0,2)$ in the 
>   $xy$-plane is which one of the following?

This is how I first attempted to solve it:

First find the slope using the following formula:
$$ s = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_1 - x_2} = \frac{1 - 2}{-1 - 0} = 1 $$

Then use the formula: $ y = sx + k $ to find $k$ by replacing $x$ and $y$ with $P(-1,1)$.
$$ 1 = 1(-1) + k $$ 
$$ k = 0 $$
Now that $s$ and $k$ are known the equation for the line defined by $P(−1,1)$ and $Q(0,2)$ is:
$$ y = 1x + 0 $$
$$ y - x = 0$$

However the answer is $ -x+y = 2 $ and I can't seem to reach this result.
Could you provide me with a hint on how to reach the correct answer?

Comment: Hey Markus. My teacher (back then) always told me to simplify my result as much as possible. This initially helped me to avoid arithmetic mistakes like the one you did. $1=1(-1)+k$ which is the same as $1=-1 +k $ might help you to spot those mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is good, except for a small arithmetic mistake: the equation $1=1(-1)+k$ implies $k=2$ since $$1=1(-1)+k\implies 1=-1+k\implies 1-(-1)=k\implies k=2.$$

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.